# Creating one generic object and using it to create another generic object in java

Tags: java, generics, element

I am trying to write the code related to Binary tree. For this I created one generic class called "Node" and used it other generic class called "Tree".

Node.java

```
public class Node<T>{

   private T element;

   private Node<T> leftObj;

   private Node<T> rightObj;

   public Node(T element){

     this.element=element;

     this.leftObj=null;

     this.rightObj=null;
   }
   //remaining are getter and setter method

}
```

Tree.java:

```
public class Tree<T>{

    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree(Node<T> node){

    this.root=node;

  }

 // remaining is adding node and deleting node method

}
```

Now I am trying to use object of these class in other class and facing issue.

abc.java

```
public class abc{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Node<Integer> tempNode = new Node<Integer>(1);

       //getting error at following line

       Tree<Node<Integer>> tree = new Tree<Node<Integer>>(tempNode);

    }

}
```

following error it is showing during Tree object creation:-

```
The constructor Tree<Node<Integer>>(Node<Integer>) is undefined
```

Please guide me through this issue and help me understand the generic concept(I am new to this topic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a *tree of nodes of integers*. It's just a tree of integers.

Consider `ArrayList<Integer>`. It's a list of integers. It's **not** a list of array elements of integers (i.e. `ArrayList<ArrayElement<Item>>`)

You simply need to change the declaration to:

```
Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>(tempNode);
```

---

When `T` is taken to be `Node<Integer>`, as you have provided, then the constructor effectively becomes

```
public Tree(Node<Node<Integer>> node){
```

You're passing it a `Node<Integer>` which does not match, hence the compiler error.

Comment: Hello Michael, Thanks. But if I am declare a Queue of these node, should I declare it as 
Queue<Integer> que = new Queue<Integer>();
or
Queue<Node> que = new Queue<Node>();
Still having little confusion.

Comment: @user2776187 Your tree is a `Tree<Integer>`. A queue of integer nodes would be `Queue<Node<Integer>>`. I suggest reading the [Oracle generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: Thank for reply. I will go through the documentation. I tried the following for declaration of Queue of node and it is working for me, therefore having some confusion:-
Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();

Comment: In that case, you are using the generic type of Queue, but the **raw type** of Node. It will give you a compiler warning, but it is not a compile error. What it means is that the node can contain any objects, not just integers. You should always avoid raw types when possible.